# Open url in webview

Tags: android, android-layout, url, webview

I am new here in Android dev.
In the below code, it will open up the Android browser.

1.Is there any possible way that i can do to open the url (matricNo) in webView instead of in Android browser without having to build new java file as in this [link](http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/10/web-view-in-android.html)?

```
final void addToAttendance(String matricNo) {
String url =  matricNo;
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
activity.startActivity(intent);  
}
```

Comment: you must need to create an activity with webview and load url in webview.

Comment: What you mean by without creating new java file? @BirajZalavadia

Comment: thank you @BirajZalavadia for your comment..
It is possible for me to open webview without creating another activity with webview..?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Activity

```
public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Context context = null;
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,WebActivity.class);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("www.javacodegeeks.com"));
                startActivity(intent);  
            }
        });
```

In Another Activity

```
 WebView wv=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
         wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         wv.loadUrl(this.getIntent().getDataString());
```

Comment: use it as explicit Intent.or call implicitly in Another activity.

Comment: sorry im new here..can you explain about 'call implicitly in Another activity'

Comment: call implicitly means call that functionality using implicit intent.(here Another activity is the name of class I have given in code).go to tutorials to understand types of intent if u r not familier with it

Comment: Good Work @Anjali +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Use following code.

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

    }

}
```

webview.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 />
```